# ARM gnu install build error with Nordic nRF51, could be path or admin

Tags: arm, gnu, toolchain, nrf51

I have been installing ARM toolchain on Windows 10 for development of Nordic nRF51, and followed instructions in their tutorial
https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/tutorials/7

when I run make for first time, I get a build error.

In detail:
I have installed toolchain in directory
C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU Tools ARM Embedded\5.3 2016q1

Coreutils is installed in directory
C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32

Nordict SDK toolchain is installed in directory
C:\Program Files (x86)\Nordic Semiconductor\NRF5_SDK

I have added following to user path environment:
C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU Tools ARM Embedded\5.3 2016q1;C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin

in directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Nordic Semiconductor\NRF5_SDK\components\toolchain\gcc
windows.makefile changed to:

```
GNU_INSTALL_ROOT := $(PROGFILES)/GNU Tools ARM Embedded/5.3 2016q1/
GNU_VERSION := 5.3
GNU_PREFIX := arm-none-eabi
```

I have checked that make and gcc are found from command line.

Following tutorial instructions at directory:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Nordic Semiconductor\NRF5_SDK\examples\peripheral\blinky\pca20006\blank\armgcc
open a cmd window (as user) and run make.

```
mkdir _build
Access is denied.
make: *** [_build] Error 1
```

error suggests unable to create _build directory.

So, from new cmd window as admin try again:

```
mkdir _build
make: *** No rule to make target `_build/Program', needed by `nrf51822_xxaa'.  Stop.
```

summary of output from make -d (in admin window):

```
Reading makefile `makefile'...
Reading makefile `../../../../../../components/toolchain/gcc/Makefile.windows' (search path) (no ~ expansion)...

 No implicit rule found for `_build/Program'.
 Finished prerequisites of target file `_build/Program'.
Must remake target `_build/Program'.
make: *** No rule to make target `_build/Program', needed by `nrf51822_xxaa'.  Stop.
```

It seems that make is failing to find makefile.windows (correct?), so I checked path by copying the target to cmd and using as:

```
cd ../../../../../../components/toolchain/gcc/
```

this changed to the correct directory.  so I believe the target path is correct.

questions:
why is an admin needed to run make, why doesn't it have correct privilege to create the _build directory?

what is failing when make is run in admin window?

thanks in advance.

Comment: See the  _"Errors like "make: No rule to make target '_build/Nordic', needed by `nrf51422_xxac". Stop can also be an indication..."_ bit in that very tutorial. 20 years since Windows 95 and the free software movement still don't accept spaces in filenames being a thing; 10 years since Vista and people still wondering why you need admin permission to modify things in Program Files; _sigh_...

Comment: thanks, that was a good pointer.  Guess I suffered wood'n'trees issue there.

BUT.  changed directory to Nordic_Semiconductor and updated path settings.

Still get the same error message though.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I may have this solved.

Uninstalled all the tools and reinstalled into a user directory (not Program Files), and made sure there were no white spaces in the directory path.

Make now builds a binary.  Seems that Nordic have released toolset that can't be installed as described...